Cannot import @coral-xyz/anchor package into React app project
I can't import Anchor into my freshly create React web app template. Why is this happening? These are my steps to replicate below. I think somebody else was having an issue with this as well here

Create a new project npx create-react-app test

Enter project directory and install Anchor npm install @coral-xyz/anchor (^0.30.0)

Add a line to App.js to import Anchor import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor"

Run the project npm run start

Open http://localhost:3000 in Safari browser

Observe error in the browser : The superclass is not a constructor.




you can see a working example with version 0.30.0 here:  https://github.com/ASCorreia/anchor-fundraiser
